# How to find Solr collection update status

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

How can I know whether a Solr Collection update command actually worked? I made only small changes (set omitTermFreqAndPositions for a couple of fields). The command I executed was

```
curl "http://localhost:8985/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=collection1"
```

I got a response

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1669},
  "success":{
    "***:*_solr":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":1597}}}}
```

Solr log file has lines like this

```
Invoked Collection Action :reload with params name=collection1&action=RELOAD&wt=json&_=1553785328234 and sendToOCPQueue=true
```

Followed by entries like

```
o.a.s.c.OverseerTaskQueue Response ZK path: /overseer/collection-queue-work/qnr-0000000018 doesn't exist.  Requestor may have disconnected from ZooKeeper
```

I have a feeling the job did not complete successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opting for an async request with an id and later querying the status works. If 123456 is the id you want to assign, add

```
&async=123456
```

as an additional query param. Once command is submitted, query like this

```
collections?action=REQUESTSTATUS&requestid=123456
```

Only query params are given. Prefix with the appropriate path.